# Zend Framework - mysql query

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, select, sum

```
$xyz = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query('select sum(value) points where userId = $userIdDB'))['suma'];
```

How that query will looks in zend framework? I need to select sum of records from DB as int.
And another question: can i make mysql queries. I dont have in real any knowledge from zend, so I please for full explanation.
What about mysql connections in zend?

Answer (score 0):

[In ZEND](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html)

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from('points',array(new Zend_Db_Expr('sum(value)')))
             ->where('userId = ?', $userIdDB);
```

When Adding Expression Columns

> Columns in SQL queries are sometimes expressions, not simply column
>   names from a table. Expressions should not have correlation names or
>   quoting applied. If your column string contains parentheses,
>   Zend_Db_Select recognizes it as an expression.
>
> You also can create an object of type Zend_Db_Expr explicitly, to
>   prevent a string from being treated as a column name. Zend_Db_Expr is
>   a minimal class that contains a single string. Zend_Db_Select
>   recognizes objects of type Zend_Db_Expr and converts them back to
>   string, but does not apply any alterations, such as quoting or
>   correlation names.

[EXAMPLE IN ZEND](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html)

```
// Build this query using Zend_Db_Expr explicitly:
//   SELECT p."product_id", p.cost * 1.08 AS cost_plus_tax
//   FROM "products" AS p

$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                    array('product_id',
                          'cost_plus_tax' =>
                              new Zend_Db_Expr('p.cost * 1.08'))
                    );
```

Comment: That will return an int value of sum(value) or table?

Comment: I fixed it now.please try it